# Convergence of an increasing sequence of operators in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I am searching for a theorem of the following form: if $T$ is a (unbounded) self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$ and $(h_n)_n$ a increasing sequence of bounded Borel functions, which converges to a (possibly) unbounded Borel function $h$, then $h_n(T)$ converges strongly to $h(T)$ with certain domain. I thought that was the theorem of Lax-Milgram (or an application of this) but I can not find it.

Answer (score 0):

The spectral theorem will give you what you want. The operator $T$ can be written as
$$
               Tx = \int_{\sigma(T)}\lambda dE(\lambda)x
$$
on the domain $\mathcal{D}(T)$ consisting of all $x \in \mathcal{H}$ for which
$$
                \int_{\sigma(T)}\lambda^{2}d\|E(\lambda)x\|^{2} < \infty.
$$
For any real Borel function $f$,
$$
                      f(T)x = \int_{\sigma(T)}f(\lambda)dE(\lambda)x
$$
defines a densely-defined selfadjoint operator $f(T)$ on the domain consisting of all $x\in\mathcal{H}$ for which
$$
          \int_{\sigma(T)}|f(\lambda)|^{2}d\|E(\lambda)x\|^{2} < \infty.
$$
In your case, $h_{n}(T)$ is defined on $\mathcal{D}(h(T))$ for all $n$, and, for $x \in \mathcal{D}(h(T))$,
\begin{align}
          & \lim_{n}\|h(T)x-h_{n}(T)x\|^{2} \\
            & =\lim_{n}\int_{\sigma(T)} |h(\lambda)-h_{n}(\lambda)|^{2}d\|E(\lambda)x\|^{2} =0.
\end{align}
Furthermore, if $\lim_{n}h_{n}(T)x$ converges for some $x$, then the monotone convergence theorem implies that $x \in \mathcal{D}(h(T))$ as defined above.